# Add Wordpress to Meteor site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, meteor

I have a Meteor app that I want to add Wordpress blogging platform to.

There doesn't need to be any integration, just:

```
http://example.com/blog/
```

Anything behind `blog/` belongs to WP.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ChristianFritz, I don't know how to get around the node server running the site, so I'm looking to the community as to how to do this.

Comment: If you downvote, please explain why this is a bad question.

Comment: You're asking about how to configure your server, such questions belong to ServerFault, not StackOverflow – try posting your question there. That said, downvote for that reason doesn't seem appropriate as well – close vote or flag is a better tool.

Comment: Also: why? Why add WP when you've got the gift of Meteor?

Comment: @HubertOG thanks, i'll ask over there.

The goal isn't to build a CMS. WP is an incredible product and rebuilding that wheel isn't something we can afford in our small shop.

Comment: @nitsujri: I downvoted your question on grounds of not showing any research effort. This is the primary reason to downvote according to the tooltip that you'll see when you hover over the downvote arrow. Your question just states your goal, but doesn't indicate any attempt of getting there and therefore doesn't really describe a problem you ran into during programming.

Comment: @nitsujri: also, could you elaborate on the problem in your comment, about node server running the site. It sounds like essential detail in order to help you with your issue. The answer I posted is speculative on what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to just run a reverse-proxy in front of meteor, and configure it such that is redirects request for "example.com/blog" to a different port on your machine. In that port you can then run WP in which ever way you prefer.

This node module is extremely leight-weight and easy to use to set up a reverse proxy: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy.